# php changing order of posts with filters

Tags: php

I am trying to create some filters on my website where the users can chose if he wants newest/oldest posts at the top and so on..
How can I do it so that the user selects the desired option then clicks save and the page refreshes showing the new order of posts, as well as show the selection made

i tried this

```
<ul>
<li><label><input type="radio" name="order_list" value="link1">Newest First</label></li>
<li><label><input type="radio" name="order_list" value="link2">Lowest Price First</label></li>
<li><label><input type="radio" name="order_list" value="link3">Highest Price First</label></li>
<li><label><input type="radio" name="order_list" value="link4">Nearest First</label></li>
</ul>


<?php
        switch($_POST['order_list']) {

case "link1":
    $res = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `posts` ORDER BY `id` DESC") or die(mysql_error());
    break;

case "link2":
    $res = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `posts` ORDER BY `price` ASC") or die(mysql_error());
    break;

case "link3":
    $res = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `posts` ORDER BY `price` DESC") or die(mysql_error());
    break;

default:
    $res = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `posts` ORDER BY `id` DESC") or die(mysql_error());
}
?>
```

i what the filter to only work when clicked "save" and to show the selections to the users account somehow so every time they log in to the website, the selections are always set as they saved it

UPDATE:

this is what the $res does:

```
if(mysql_num_rows($res) > 0){
        while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($res)){
            $id = $row['id'];
            $user_id = $row['user_id'];
            $price = $row['price'];
            $cover = $row['cover'];
            $title = $row['title'];
```

Comment: If i'm not mistaken, the script you showed only tells us that whatever option the user picks, php will use the correct query depending on the choice. What are you doing with the $res?

Comment: i updated the post above. it pulls out the info from the database pretty much

Answer (score 0):

you need to add a form and submit button for this and make `action=""` to reload the same page with submission like this

```
<?php
$order_list = "";

if(isset($_POST['submit'], $_POST['order_list']))
{
    $order_list = $_POST['order_list'];
}

$link1 = "";
$link2 = "";
$link3 = "";
$link4 = "";

        switch($order_list) {

        case "link1":
            $res = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `posts` ORDER BY `id` DESC") or die(mysql_error());
            $link1 = "checked";
            break;

        case "link2":
            $res = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `posts` ORDER BY `price` ASC") or die(mysql_error());
            $link2 = "checked";
            break;

        case "link3":
            $res = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `posts` ORDER BY `price` DESC") or die(mysql_error());
            $link3 = "checked";
            break;

        default:
            $res = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `posts` ORDER BY `id` DESC") or die(mysql_error());
            $link4 = "checked";
        }
?>


<form action=""  method="post" >
    <ul>
        <li><label><input type="radio" name="order_list" value="link1" <?php echo $link1;?>>Newest First</label></li>
        <li><label><input type="radio" name="order_list" value="link2" <?php echo $link2;?>>Lowest Price First</label></li>
        <li><label><input type="radio" name="order_list" value="link3" <?php echo $link3;?>>Highest Price First</label></li>
        <li><label><input type="radio" name="order_list" value="link4" <?php echo $link4;?>>Nearest First</label></li>
    </ul>
    <input type="submit" value="Save" name="submit" />
</from>
```

Comment: nothing happens when i click save.. btw take a look at the update i posted with what $res does when called

Answer (score 0):

Hi put your  inside a form , that will do

```
<form action           ='<?php $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>' method='post'>
<ul>
<li><label><input type ="radio" name="order_list" value="link1">Newest First</label></li>
<li><label><input type ="radio" name="order_list" value="link2">Lowest Price First</label></li>
<li><label><input type ="radio" name="order_list" value="link3">Highest Price First</label></li>
<li><label><input type ="radio" name="order_list" value="link4">Nearest First</label></li>
</ul>
<input type            ="submit" value='Search'>
</form>


<?php
switch($_POST['order_list']) {

case "link1":
    $res = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `posts` ORDER BY `id` DESC") or die(mysql_error());
    break;

case "link2":
    $res = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `posts` ORDER BY `price` ASC") or die(mysql_error());
    break;

case "link3":
    $res = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `posts` ORDER BY `price` DESC") or die(mysql_error());
    break;

default:
    $res = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `posts` ORDER BY `id` DESC") or die(mysql_error());
}
?>
```

Comment: tried adding <?php $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>, didn't do anything when clicked save

Comment: @Bamba here is the complete code , well need lil fine tuning :P but its working

Comment: what did you change? everything looks the same.. but i tried it anyways and no change

Comment: @Bamba what is actually your problem/ requirements ?

Comment: i want the user to select which order they want to display the ads in then click on the save button. Once clicked save, the page will rearrange the posts as they chose. Their choice will also be saved to their user_id so that next time they go on the website they will see the same choice selected already (so they don't have to do it again)